Split master table into table with one row - Power Query
I have one table with several rows (24), I need to split this table into 24 pages - each row = own page.
I tried function table.split, but I was not able to create different pages. I got a list with text "table" but not different pages with one line.

PQ does not support creating multiple pages/tables/sheets from a single query. You'll need to effectively create separate queries to do that. This reference might be helpful: Power Query / Get & Transform - Split Master as separate sheets
